# Creating subdomainin codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain

i am creating a flat management software in PHP (codeigniter).
now client need to create different sub domains for different builders but should maintain only single database.

Comment: Create another CI instance/codebase and connect to the same database?

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-make-multiple-websitesubdomain-of-your-main-site-in-codeigniter-with-same-code-and-database-dynamically/

Comment: Please let me know if this link helped you

Comment: wow it works. thanks a lot ricky

Comment: You are most welcome don't forget to share with your friends and keep visiting http://w3code.in you will find more usefull content in future

Comment: Nice tutorial @Ricky one suggestion though... Use `$this->input->server('HTTP_HOST')` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. These values can be cleansed by the CI security class and if they don't exist the method will return false. Which is much better than having to do all the `isset` checks yourself :P

Comment: Thanks mic for the feedback will check and implement